# Why is response considering list item as string in Django rest?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working on a case where when a user sends a post request with data, the data will be stored in a table and response all the objects in that table.

I'm trying to implement `JsonResponse` in `django-rest-framework`.

I created two of my model fields as `ListFields` and serialized the query set for response.

But when the server is sending response, instead of being list items, they're shown as string values.

Here's my code

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from djongo.models import ListField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    cast = ListField()
    scenes = ListField()
```

**views.py:**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from app1.models import Post
from app1.serializers import PostSerializer

class CreateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.POST
        post = Post(**data)
        post.save()
        dat = Post.objects.all()
        print(dat)
        serializer = PostSerializer(dat, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from app1.models import Post

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

**output:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "['This is title']",
        "cast": "['1,2,3']",
        "scenes": "['4,5,6']"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "['This is title']",
        "cast": "['10,20,30']",
        "scenes": "['40,50,60']"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "['This is title']",
        "cast": "['10,20,30']",
        "scenes": "['40,50,60']"
    }
]
```

Here the cast and scenes fields are shown as strings instead of Lists.

BTW. I'm using MongoDB and the list fields are not being saved as arrays. They are being saved as a string where the items are separated by commas.

Where am I going wrong? What should I do to make the fields in response to behave as list fields instead of strings?

Comment: Show the code for PostSerializer. Also can you check how that field is being saved? Is it definitely saved as a list? Really you should also be using your serializer to save, rather than getting the raw POST.

Comment: Please see the updated content.

Comment: So like I said, the problem is in the saving, not the response. Also like I said, you should have been using the serializer to save them, which would probably avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing it in the DRF way :( As ***Daniel Roseman*** said, you should use the serializer to save them. Anyway, try the following snippet

```
class CreateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        post_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        post_serializer.is_valid(True)
        post_serializer.save()
        return Response(post_serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your way of considering the request and saving it. As suggested by JPG, it wouldn't be a problem if you save the response as object after serializing it.